# How to extract number from text, which is between <br> <<b> - Xpath

Tags: c#, xpath

I do not know how to do than, so I do not post any my code :/

```
<div class="style2 f_left">Wyprawa do <b>Tana</b><br>Czas trwania: <b>32</b> minut.<br>Szansa powodzenia: <b>75 %</b>.<br></div>
```

From this div I need to extract number 32(it's random generated)

Answer (score 1):

XPath is an option, but since you don't post any requirement for it I suggest some other solutions.

You could use a regular expression to get the number:

```
<b>(\d+?)<\/b>
```

The answer will be in the first group.

Since you're working with HTML you could also use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) or similar solutions to step through it and get the value from there.

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you give me exmple of this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript you could do as below:

```
var num = parseInt($('#DivIdHere').text().match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

just get all text from < div > element and substring everything between "Czas trwania:" and "minut", no need to use complex xPath